# Dark artifacts when rendering CAD-type model

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

I'm new to Blender (but I've known Maya for years), and any help y'all can offer would be greatly appreciated!

I'm having a problem similar to the ones in these posts, but the solutions offered there haven't solved my problem:

- [[SOLVED] Weird shading bug and rough render (CYCLES)](http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?313785-Weird-shading-bug-and-rough-render-%28CYCLES%29)
- [Shader artifacts rendering in some spots of the mesh](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/19091/shader-artifacts-rendering-in-some-spots-of-the-mesh)

I'm working with this model that my company bought for a project:

- [Full Kitchen Scene 3](http://turbosquid.com/3d-models/3ds-max-kitchen-scene-set/669863)

The mesh seems to be generated with a CAD program. It's not pretty; lots of long skinny triangles and whatnot.

I'll focus on one example of the artifacts I'm getting.

Here's what I mean about ugly geometry:
[image: ugly geometry shown in edit mode]

When I render it with Cycles, it has dark areas:
[image: ugly geometry rendered darkly by Cycles]

The mesh is ugly, but the normals are all pointing out and I've removed duplicate vertices.

Has anyone run into this before? I could really use a hand!

Comment: Adding edge split modifier should solve your problem

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/734/599

Answer (score 5):

Thanks Denis! (I can't comment cause I'm new.)

I think I've got a good solution going:

[image: Eh? Eh?]

With the object selected, I went to the the Object Data tab of the Properties Panel, and unchecked Auto Smooth.

Then, like Denis suggested, I added an Edge Split modifier. I checked Edge Angle and set it to 180 degrees.

This will work for me. Does anybody have any other suggestions for future reference?