# Strange shadows on the model

Tags: shadows

I'm getting strange shadows on the model:[image] the normals are ok (already tried to recalculate them) so I have no idea what this could be.
Any suggestion?

Comment: See [Shader artifacts rendering in some spots of the mesh](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/19091/2217), [Smooth shaded model has odd shading](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/23596/2217) and [How to smooth shade an object while retaining hard edges?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/734/2217)

Answer (score 1):

Add an edge split modifier, should clean up the messy normals.

Answer (score 0):

If you cut those holes using a boolean modifier, your topology is probably mesed up. See: [Applied boolean modifier leaving shading artifacts with flat shading](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/13554/applied-boolean-modifier-leaving-shading-artifacts-with-flat-shading)

Using auto smooth will most likely fix this issue.

Comment: thanks for your reply, but unfortunately this didn't work